# Why datatable is adding new records and keeping the old ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, frontend

I'm using datatable plug-in for jquery. When e load the page, the datatable is empty. After user click in a specific button it makes a XMLHttpRequest that returns data from database and then i add that data to the datatable (with the function `drawDataTable`). Everything is ok if i do one request.

Everytime i do another request the datatable keeps the old ones and adds the new ones. THis leads to rows with duplicated data.

Here is the code:

```js
function drawDataTable(pData) {
    console.log("Call of drawDataTable!!!");

    //change display
    document.getElementById("dataTableCard").style.display = "block";

    //destroy old instatiated table and create a new one
/*    var dataTable = document.querySelector("#dataTable .tableBody");
    htmlChildsRemover(dataTable);*/

    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "scrollY": "400px",
        "paging": false
    });

            var p1 = pData['p1'];
            var p2 = pData['p2'];
            var p3 = pData['p3'];
            var p4 = pData['p4'];
            var p5 = pData['p5'];
            var p6 = pData['p6'];

            //add rows
            $('#addRows').on('click', function() {
           
                    for (var idxT in p1) {

                        table.row.add([
                            p1[idxT],
                            p2[idxT],
                            p3[idxT],
                            p4[idxT],
                            p5[idxT],
                            p6[idxT]
                        ]).draw(false);

                    } //endFor

            });

            // Automatically add rows 
            $('#addRows').click();
            
} //drawDataTable
```

```html
      <div class="card mb-3" id="dataTableCard">
        <div class="card-header"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Data Table Example</div>
        <div class="card-body">
<button id="addRows"></button><!-- Hidden button -->
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered tableType1" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <!-- This is a "base-skeleton for datatable" -->
              <thead>
                <tr class="tableHead">
                  <th class="head1">p1</th>
                  <th class="head2">p2</th>
                  <th class="head3">p3</th>
                  <th class="head4">p4</th>
                  <th class="head5">p5</th>
                  <th class="head6">p6</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th class="foot1">p1</th>
                  <th class="foot2">p2</th>
                  <th class="foot3">p3</th>
                  <th class="foot4">p4</th>
                  <th class="foot5">p5</th>
                  <th class="foot6">p6</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody class="tableBody"> </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

**Note:** I've added `table.destroy();` to destroy the old one and then i create a new one. I even tryed to remove his rows with a function that removes html childs of given parent (`htmlChildsRemover(parent)`). But still keeping the old records on datatable.

**The data that is returned from each request is good, so i think that its something in datatable plugin that is keeping the old records.**

HOw can i solve this? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add `table.clear()` before adding rows:

```
table.clear(); <<<<<here
for (var idxT in p1) {
                table.row.add([
                    p1[idxT],
                    p2[idxT],
                    p3[idxT],
                    p4[idxT],
                    p5[idxT],
                    p6[idxT]
                ]).draw(false);

            } //endFor
```